# Can i have multiple Google Play Developer Accounts for different Niche Apps?

Tags: firebase, google-play, admob, google-play-console

I want to release two different Android Apps, Both are complete different niche and I wanted to keep both the account separate, Reason; I am planning to release more similar niche apps in the related Google Play Developer Account. However, as per the google policies, I cant have two google play developer accounts. So how do I manage this situation?

I do not want to keep both the apps in the same developer account as one app is in travel and one is in the finance niche.

Kindly suggest to me what is the best solution. Also, I will be integrating firebase and Admob in both apps. So can I use Firebase and AdMob from any one of these accounts and use it in both apps?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 different play console account ( 2 different google account )

You can use firebase ( with creating different project )and admob from one account.

Comment: Yes, I need two diff account but is it allowed to keep 2 diff console account?